$\{X_t\}$ is a version of $\{Y_t\}$ but $Y_t$ is continous and $X_t$ is not
Suppose $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are both defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with $P$ being probability measure and $\mathcal{F}$ the Borel sigma algebra on $[0, \infty)$. And distribution for $\{X_t\}$ is defined as:
$$
X_t(\omega)= \begin{cases}1 & \text { if } t=\omega \\ 0 & \text { otherwise }\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
Y_t(\omega)=0 \quad \text { for all }(t, \omega) \in[0, \infty) \times[0, \infty)
$$
I am tring to show $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ have the same distribution but $Y_t$ is continous and $X_t$ is not.
$P(X_t = Y_t) = P(X_t = 0)$, but I'm stuck at showing $X_t = 0$ almost surely.

It depends on $P$. How is it defined?

This is false in general.
For fixed $t$ we have $P(X_t=1)=P(\{t\}).$
If $P$ assigns a positive weight to any nonnegative number $t_0,$ then $P(X_{t_0}=1)>0=P(Y_{t_0}=1).$
If $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, then for any $t$ separately $P(X_t=1)=0$ so that the variables $X_t$ and $Y_t$ have the same distribution.

Given the conditions, for each fixed $t_i$ we have $X_{t_i}(\omega)=1$ if $t_1=\omega$ and $0$ otherwise. However, since $\omega$ is a value from the continuous distribution $[0,\infty)$,  $\omega=t_i$ is zero. Therefore $P(X_{t_n}=0)=1$. Since by definition $Y_t(\omega)=0\quad\forall (t,\omega)$ therefore $P(X_t=Y_t)$ which leads to $P(X_t=0)$ Therefore $P(X_t=0)=1$ which is $0$ by deduction, which will determine $P(X_t=Y_t)=P(X_t=0)=1$ showing that $X_t=0$.
